# Selection sort in python indexing

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, selection-sort

My code seems to be working fine if i put (n-1) and n in the range function of the first for loop, which I am not able to understand.Please help

```
 def selec(arr):
    n=len(arr)

    for i in range(n):
         min=i
         for j in range(i+1,n):
             if arr[j]<arr[min]:
                  min=j

    arr[i],arr[min]=arr[min],arr[i]
    return arr

print(selec([2, 6, 5, 7, 1, 4]))
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. It doesn't appear to work at all as provided.

Comment: your code is correct except for the indenting.

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly indent your code, everything works fine:

```
def selec(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        min = i
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if arr[j]<arr[min]:
                min = j 
        arr[i],arr[min]=arr[min],arr[i]
    return arr
```

Comment: I was not comfortable with stack overflow editing techniques,there is no indentation problem.I just dint understand the different solutions on internet\

Comment: ok... then I think I cannot understand the original question.